# How can I prove that $\mathbb P\{X\leq x\}=\int_{-\infty}^x f_X(t)dt$?

Tags: probability

$$\mathbb P\{X\leq x\}=\int_{\Omega }\boldsymbol 1_{X^{-1}(-\infty,x]}(\omega )d\mathbb P(\omega )=\int_{\Omega }\boldsymbol 1_{(-\infty,x]}(X(\omega ))d\mathbb P(\omega ),$$

how can I continue ? I guess I have to do the substitution $t=X(\omega )$, but I don't really know how to manage with the $d\mathbb P$.

Comment: I think that $\Bbb P\{X\le x\}=\Bbb P\left(\{\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega)\le x\}\right)=\int_{-\infty}^xf_X(t)dt$ is the definition of the measure $\Bbb P$ on the measure space $(\Omega,\Bbb P)$

Comment: @Masacroso: And what is the definition of $f_X$ ?

Comment: mmm... check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Formal_definition)